# React needs to render twice in order to update my value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, jsx

Here is my premise:

I have a cartItems state, here is its basic structure.

When empty:

```
cartItems: []
```

When populated:

```
cartItems: [{
    id: 999,
    date: "Wed Jan 24 2018 19:30:00 GMT-0500 (EST)",
    tickets: [{
        amount: 49.99,
        quantity: 2
    }]
},{
    id: 998,
    date: "Wed Jan 24 2018 19:30:00 GMT-0500 (EST)",
    tickets: [{
        amount: 49.99,
        quantity: 1
    }]
}]
```

I also have in my app a cart that displays the ticket quantity total.

So in order to display these totals, I'm using something like this in JSX:

```
<span className="my-total">
{                             
    this.props.cartItems.reduce((grandTotal, item) => {
        return grandTotal + item.tickets.reduce((runningTotal, ticket) => {
            return runningTotal + ticket.quantity || 0
        }, 0);
     }, 0)
}
</span>
```

So basically I am looping through this.props.cartItems to tally up a total of tickets and providing reduce a starting point of 0.

However, when I *first* add tickets to the cart my total is not updated. If I console log the returned value I get 0. Although my cartItems state is updated correctly and I can see the newly added tickets.

Upon triggering the updateCart method, I am either updating the quantity in the tickets array or pushing a new object to cartItems, and then updating the state of cartItems.

But then, the second time I add the tickets using the exact same updateCart method, the total is now updated correctly. If I console log the returned value I get the correct amount of tickets.

I would expect that when my cartItems state is first updated that React would re-render and that my reduce would kick in and update the displayed value.

Comment: How are you updating state and displaying it?

Comment: The state is displayed within the JSX in a span (as seen above), and updated via a cartUpdate method. This method depending on the scenario will either add tickets to an existing item or push a new item into the cartItems array, then setState({cartItems})

Comment: There's no way anyone can help you without seeing your actual React components

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of pieces of that are missing to detect the actual problem. Nonetheless here is a solution assuming few things:

1. Your state contains `cartItems` and `grandTotal`
2. The actual data comes vis `this.props`
3. You updated the state in `willReceiveProps`

```js
state = {
    cartItems: [],
    grandTotal: 0
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const grandTotal = nextProps.cartItems.reduce((grandTotal, item) => {
        return grandTotal + item.tickets.reduce((runningTotal, ticket) => {
            const total = ticket.amount * ticket.quantity;

            return Number.isNaN(total) ? runningTotal : runningTotal + total;
        });
    });

    this.setState({
        cartItems: nextProps.cartItems,
        grandTotal
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                    this.state.cartItems.map((data) => <Draw key={data.id} data />)
                }
            </ul>
            <p>{this.state.grandTotal}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help Vijay! The error was actually syntax related. See edit above if you're curious.

Comment: You are welcome. One question remains, don't you wanna correct your calculation? `const total = ticket.amount * ticket.quantity;` and then `return Number.isNaN(total) ? runningTotal : runningTotal + total;`

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

This has been solved. The error is in the reduce function:

```
    this.props.cartItems.reduce((grandTotal, item) => {
        return grandTotal + item.tickets.reduce((runningTotal, ticket) => {
            return runningTotal + ticket.quantity || 0
        }, 0);
     }, 0)
```

At this line:

```
return runningTotal + ticket.quantity || 0
```

I thought that this would evaluate ticket.quantity and if it was undefined change it to 0, however it did not do that. Rather it would change the entire expression to = 0 when ticket.quantity is undefined.